How to set the timezone in a Cloud Storage trigger? (Cloud Functions for Firebase)
Is there a way in the 2nd generation of Cloud Function to set a different timezone inside a Cloud Storage Trigger?
This is useful, specially when we use methods like FieldValue.serverTimestamp().

Firstly, FieldValue.serverTimestamp() is a Firestore concept, and doesn't have anything to do with Cloud Storage.  They are completely different products with different use cases.
Secondly, Firestore timestamps don't have a timezone associated with them.  A Firestore timestamp is just two numbers that measure the number of seconds and nanoseconds since the unix epoch in UTC.  These numbers don't change based on whatever sense of timezone your application might have.  If you see a timezone in the Firebase or Google Cloud console related to a Firestore timestamp, that is taken from your computer's clock's timezone.  If you change your computer's clock's timezone, that will cause the console to render the timezone differently.
See:

Firestore Timestamp.fromDate not UTC
can I change timezone saved in Firestore timestamp field?


Could you close this question? I'd open a similar one

Why don't you just delete it?  I can't do that.  Or just accpet the answer as correct so that this information is preserved for others in the future.
